# Authenticating using a various amount of clients with oidc's JWT

Tags: authentication, oauth, identity, openid-connect

I need to protect a WebApi and using oAuth. There are loads of approaches but I can't really find the one that fits my needs.

I'm trying to protect my service with oAuth but i'm not sure how. This is just a story about my experience digging in to the world of authentication / authorization.

I'm trying to develop a service in which I want users to identify themselves. I may want to create a users repository but for now I'm fine with just allowing logins from 3rd party providers like Google, Microsoft, Twitter etc.

I'm writing a backend using the microservices architecture (AspNet Core (2.2)) with a gateway API routing requests to the desired microservice. So far so good, verything runs fine!

My service is presented using a front-end framework (Angular) which communicates with the gateway API. Again, all fine here.

Now my problem is, that I want users to identify themselves. I tried digging in the world of authentication and authorization and got overwhelmed by terms, do's and don'ts and a huge amount of complexity. Also, there are a lot of websites tackeling the problem partially, but fail to explain how a complete system should come together.

First I tried running my own identity server using the IdentityServer4 package which is really nice by the way but again, here comes the complexity. I got the front-end to grab a JWT Token, but then the backend fails to validate it. Also, I can imaging that deploying an identityserver instance to a production environment requires a lot of in-depth which I don't have.

I tried auth0.com, but I didn't get the entire system to work. Again, I was able to log in using the front-end website, but the configureing the backend and getting it to validate incoming requests was more difficult.

I also understand that OpenID Connect (OIDC) is kind of a super-set of oAuth, adding authorization capabilities. Again I think there's a lot of information available but nothing that really fits my needs.

So in short, my question is that I have a lot of (ASP.NET Core WebApi) services and (one or more) a front-end system, which I want to protect partially using authentication and authorisation.

I would like the front-end to aquire a JWT Token, which should be passed to the gateway using an Authentication header. Now I want the gateway to route these requests to the desired microservice, which validates the token using the identity service and either accepts or denies the request depending on the user's permission.

What systems or services do you recommend? I sense that IdentityServer4 really fits my needs. If that's the case, I just need to dig in. The learning curve is huge, but OK. However, I don't like spending a large amount of time on a system that doesn't work for me.

So again, what solution do you recomment, preferrably free of charge ;)

Comment: If you are using .net core then yes go with Identity server 4.    Security is hard i would expect a huge learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  [identity server 4](http://docs.identityserver.io)  it works perfectly, you have to define your list of clients in your identity server and it has to be the same as in your angular applications, example: **appsettings.json**

```
...
"Clients": {
"Confidential": {},
"Public": {

  "angularapp1": {
    "ClientId": "spa-app1",
    "ClientName": "client application1",
    "ClientUri": "http://localhost:4200", // for development case
    "RequireConsent": false,
    "AllowedGrantTypes": [ "implicit" ], // the authorization flow to use
    "AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser": true,
    "RedirectUris": [
      "http://localhost:4200/#/auth-callback#", // post login redirect
      "http://localhost:4200/assets/html/silent-refresh-redirect.html" // silent refresh 
    ],
    "PostLogoutRedirectUris": [ "http://localhost:4200?postLogout=true" ],
    "FrontChannelLogoutUri": "http://localhost:4200?frontchannellogout=true",
    "FrontChannelLogoutSessionRequired": true,
    "AllowedCorsOrigins": [ "http://localhost:4200" ],
    "AllowedScopes": [ "openid", "profile", "email" ], //alowed scopes
    "IdentityTokenLifetime": 18000,
    "AccessTokenLifetime": 18000
  },
 "angularapp2": {...}


...
}
```

for the frontend side the best choice is to use the implicit flow so you can provide access tokens to your angular client with an expiration lifetime, it's better than using authorization code flow because you have to store the secret key in your angular app and thet secret is used to generate access tokens, it's not secure

[image]

i use [oidc-client.js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) it's a very helpful JavaScript library with useful methods and events

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm just missing one aspect. When I completed the login and received a token in Angular, and then make a call to the backend (with that token). How do I validate the token and check permission (scopes?)